# Complexity of maximization of entropy of Hamming distance of bitstrings

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, np-complete, information-theory, coding-theory

We have a set of possible "key"s $S$ represented by bitstrings of length $k$. In other words, $S$ contains an arbitrary subset of all bitstrings of length $k$. For example, when $k=3$, it can be $S = \{001, 010, 011, 000, 111\}$. I would like to find a "guess", which maximizes the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) of itself and the possible keys, assuming that the keys in $S$ are drawn with equal possibility. For instance, say the guess is $g = 001$, then the Hamming distances are $H(001, 001) = 0$, $H(001, 010) = 2$, $H(001, 011) = 1$, $H(001, 000) = 1$, and $H(001, 111) = 2$. It follows that the entropy is $E = -\left[\frac{1}{5}\log(\frac{1}{5})+\frac{2}{5}\log(\frac{2}{5})+\frac{2}{5}\log(\frac{2}{5})\right]$. A superior guess would be $g = 000$ or $g = 111$, which actually maximizes the entropy. There will be multiple guesses that maximize the entropy, and finding any of them is enough.

I actually have two related questions:

1. How hard is it to find an optimal guess that maximizes the entropy? (In terms of N/NP/NPC/NPH, etc)
2. How hard is it to find the maximum entropy?

I have previously posted a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3583663/maximize-the-entropy-of-hamming-distance) on math.SE, and a comment suggested that full enumeration is probably the best algorithm I can get. The problem sounds even harder than the $k$-partition problem, so I guess it is NP-complete or NP-hard.